# How can I pass a method with generic constraints as a Func<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, func, type-constraints

Within a defined abstract class I want to create two static methods which can  be passed to a method defined as such :

```
public static void AddType<T>(
    Func<XmlReader, T> ReaderFunc,
    Func<T, XmlWriter> WriterFunc ){
    /*Magic stuff happens here*/
}
```

This would be the Static Class :

```
public abstract class XmlModel : IXmlSerializable{

    static XmlModel( ){
        //Type Inference kicks in with other tests, but not this one T_T
        MyStaticClass.AddType( ReadModel, WriteModel );
    }

    private static T ReadModel<T>( XmlReader Reader ) where T : XmlModel, new( ){
        T Model = new T( );
        T.ReadXml( Reader );
        return T;
    }

    private static void WriteModel<T>( T Model, XmlWriter Writer ) where T : XmlModel{
        T.WriteXml( Writer );
    }

    public abstract void ReadXml( XmlReader Reader );
    public abstract void WriteXml( XmlWriter Writer );
}
```

The reason I want to be able to pass `ReadModel` and `WriteModel` to the `AddType` method is because that method belongs to a class which contains the following extension methods that will ultimately make it very, very easy for me to read and write values from and to Xml :

```
public static class ReaderWriters{
    private static Dictionary<Type, object>
        _dctTypeReader = new Dictionary<Type, object>( );
    private static Dictionary<Type, object>
        _dctTypeWriter = new Dictionary<Type, object>( );

    /// <summary>
    /// Add type reader/writer pair.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of object to be read and written.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="ReaderFunc">Func which returns value read.</param>
    /// <param name="WriterFunc">Func which writes value.</param>
    public static void AddType<T>(
        Func<XmlReader, T> ReaderFunc,
        Func<T, XmlWriter> WriterFunc ) {
        _dctTypeReader.Add( typeof( T ), ReaderFunc );
        _dctTypeWriter.Add( typeof( T ), WriterFunc );
    }

    public static T Read<T>( this XmlReader Reader ){
        if ( _dctTypeReader.ContainsKey( ( Key = typeof( T ) ) ) || ( Key =
             _dctTypeReader.Keys.FirstOrDefault( K => typeof( T ).BaseType == K ) ) != null ) {
            if ( Reader.ReadToFollowing( typeof( T ).Name ) )
                return ( _dctTypeReader[ Key ] as Func<XmlReader, T> )( Reader );
            else
                throw new XmlException( string.Format( "Failed to read into type {0}. Value was not found at expected location.", typeof( T ).Name ) );
        } else
            throw new KeyNotFoundException(
                string.Format( "Please define a method for reading objects of type {0}", typeof( T ).Name ) );
    }

    public static void Write<T>( this T toWrite, XmlWriter Writer ){
        /*Magic happens here*/
    }
}
```

In this way I would be able to inherit XmlModel :

```
public class Foo : XmlModel{
    public override void ReadXml( XmlReader Reader ){
        /*Magic Happens Here*/
    }
    public override void WriteXml( XmlWriter Writer ){
        /*Magic Happens Here*/
    }
}
```

and be able to say `Foo Model = SomeXmlReader.Read<Foo>( )` and `Model.Write( SomeXmlWriter )`...

Is what I am trying to accomplish here possible? I mean, I've pretty much resigned myself to having to do this manually with every class inheriting my `XmlModel` class, but if there was some way to do this in a way that I only had to define it ONCE within the abstract class, that would make me so happy...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you're going for is doable. Most of the difficulty you're running into seems to be from an over-use of statics. In general, don't use static unless you have a really good reason to. This problem is solvable just by making your class non-static and putting the generic implementation at the class level.

In the example code below I just dropped static from XmlModel, moved the generic parameter to the class level, and renamed a few variables to follow standard naming conventions (lowercase names for local variables and parameters). Unless I'm misunderstanding, this should do more or less what you're looking for.

```
public static class MyStaticClass
{
// Define other methods and classes here
    public static void AddType<T>(
        Func<XmlReader, T> ReaderFunc,
        Action<T, XmlWriter> WriterFunc ){
        /*Magic stuff happens here*/
    }
}


public abstract class XmlModel<T> where T : XmlModel<T>, new( )
{
    public XmlModel( ){
        //Type Inference kicks in with other tests, but not this one T_T
        MyStaticClass.AddType<T>( ReadModel, WriteModel );
    }

    private T ReadModel( XmlReader reader )  
    {
        T model = new T( );
        model.ReadXml( reader );
        return model;
    }

    private void WriteModel( T model, XmlWriter writer ) 
    {
        model.WriteXml( writer );
    }

    public abstract void ReadXml( XmlReader reader );
    public abstract void WriteXml( XmlWriter writer );
}
```

- List item

Comment: So how would I inherit this abstract class then? `public class Foo : XmlModel<Foo>`? Also, when I declare a class inheriting I get the following error : `XmlModel<Foo>.XmlModel( ) is inaccessible due to it's protection level`

Comment: There are a few problems with this solution, though it's close. First is that declaring the abstract class constructor private makes classes that inherit the abstract class explode ( can't access private constructor ). Second is that if I were to declare multiple instances of the same class inheriting my abstract class, AddType<T> would be called for each instance. AddType<T> only needs to be called once for each class ( hence the static constructor ).

Comment: You're right on the constructor being public, but you can't use the static constructor. Instead you'll have to update your AddType method to track the types which have already been added and skip duplicates. Another option is to have a threadsafe static property in XmlModel to tell if you need to call AddType or not. Let me know if you'd like examples of those solutions.